Best way to share audio files on my website
I am developing a music-sharing app using Django and React. My problem is that on the home page, I could very well have up to 100 different songs, with each audio file being around 40 MB. This of course causes performance issues, and I don't know how to solve them. At the moment I am using Google Cloud storage for hosting audio files, should I switch to something else? Is the issue even in Google Cloud? I am new to handling a growing amount of data on the website so all suggestions are welcome. Thank you!

If you mean you're having 100 <audio> tags loading audio, that's the issue. You'll want to, well, not do that, e.g. by some client-side scripting ensuring that those <audio> tags are only loaded when required, or maybe better yet by having a single <audio> tag that handles playing, and you'd change the src on that tag accordingly...
Using a Google Cloud storage bucket is in fact perfectly fine for this.
